# refreshing values with ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox

hey everyone i have problem dealing with ng-init or maybe ng-init isn't the solution , all right i'm using ng-init to initialize data inside my dynamic combobox like this :

```
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="l in list |orderBy: 'idfonction' as filtered_result track by l.idfonction " >   

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

<h5>{{l.nomfonction}} : </h5>

    </div>


  <div class="col-md-4" > 
        <div class="input-group">


 <select ng-init="newObject[l.idfonction] = inifonction[0]"  ng-model="newObject[l.idfonction]"  ng-options="  fct for fct in inifonction   "  class="form-control">


        </select>
            <span class="input-group-btn" >
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" ng-disabled="newObject[l.idfonction] != 'KO' " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mycollapse_{{l.idfonction}}">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
            </button>
            </span>


        </div>

 </div>
```

my scope data :

```
 $scope.inifonction = ["N/P","N/A","OK","KO"];
```

and my output of this `ng-model="newObject[l.idfonction]"` look like this :

```
Object {1: "N/A", 2: "OK", 3: "N/A", 4: "N/P", tab: "N/P"}
```

and am getting this as a result : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMy7m.png

for now everything is great ng-init is working great and it's initializing data 
but the result in the picture is inside a modal the modal is coming out of this table every time i click on that link i get a modal :

[image]

now here comes the problem when i select something in one of the select box like this : 
 [image]

then i open another link ( exemple : the one below PDCR3 from  the table ) , the modal shows up with the selection that i just made , what i mean why it's not executing that ng-init everytime i click on the link why it conserving what i just edited .

Thanks to any support .

Answer (score 1):

`ng-init` will only run when Angular processes the HTML, which will generall occur when the page is loaded from the server for the first time (which is why it's an init-ialize command).

I've never seen `ng-init` used in a production environment.  It's usually just used in demos on websites and blogs talking about Angular features because it's a quick way to initialize a scope variable without having to create a controller.

Since you want this to run whenever a link is clicked, perhaps that should be in a link click function, similar to this:

```
$scope.linkClick = function(listitem) {
    $scope.newObject[listitem.idfonction] = $scope.inifonction[0];
    ... code to open modal ...
}
```

Then in your HTML, you may need to change your link to something like this:

```
<a ng-click="linkClick(l)">PCDR3</a>
```

Comment: i know first i tied to make it this way but  `l.idfonction` it's not a static number and if you do it like that it will turn out undefined ps the only solution here maybe is to find another to initialize data ps then i can make anything in click function but like this i cant use the ng-init do you have a guess to make that work ps thanks for answering

Comment: In the ``ng-click``, I have it passing the ``l`` object which is dynamic for each listitem.  This is received by the ``$scope.linkClick()`` function.  This way you can pass the data you need to your function.  How is that not working?

Comment: it turn out to be an undefined value ps do you know that `l` is the whole object and your trying to set a value of an object without a loop how's that even possible if you try to click on the first link `$scope.newObject[listitem[?].idfonction]= anything` i don't think it works that way :/ ps thanks for replying